# Why is my USB drive treated as an internal hard disk drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I have a 8 GB Sandisk Cruzer USB drive that I just purchased a few weeks ago. I use two systems, viz Windows XP and Windows 7 Professional. When I connect my drive to Windows 7, it's working properly as an external USB drive; I can remove it by safely remove option. But an issue is arising when I connect it to a Windows XP machine. It's treated as an internal hard drive!! I cannot even safely remove it.

The file system is [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32). I used other USB drives too, but this is kind of weird; I've never seen this issue.. What is the reason and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system is not the issue nor is it as what it shows up, that's just a user representation. To avoid file corruption you need to have that drive disable its write caching.

Now, I don't remember the XP path, but it should be in its properties.
Right click the drive > Properties > look for Policies and select Quick removal if it's not already selected.

Under 7 I know it's under Right click the drive > Properties > hardware > select the drive in question > Properties button > Policies tab.

I also have a drive, it's one of those 1,8" pocket USB hard drives. Ideally, it would be best to show up as a removable drive, but it shows up as a plain HDD, which has its advantages when trying to boot up OSes, and it's set for quick removal and formatted with NTFS. I have no issues with it even if most of the times I just yank it out of the USB port whenever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP you can change it by opening properties on the device:

- Click hardware tab
- Select the USB drive
- Click properties
- Change setings
- Policies tab
- Select Quick Removal

In a simple way, that choice turns off the cache feature on a USB/HDD drive (external). That will make it respond a little bit slower, but you can eject it quickly.